# How to remove monitoring from azure storage account before deleting it

Tags: azure, azure-storage, monitoring

This is a sub task of removing a storage account. I’m wondering if there is a check list of monitoring to remove. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> How to remove monitoring from Azure storage account before deleting it

To remove monitoring from the Azure storage account you can use the below command.

**First Command:**

```
az monitor diagnostic-settings delete --name <name storage account > --resource "resource id of storage account "
```

The above command executes and it deletes existing diagnostic settings for the specified resource.

**Output:**

[image]

**Second command:**

You can use the **`az monitor log-analytics workspace linked-storage show`** it will show the log-analytics workspace linked-storage.

If you need to delete the log-analytics workspace linked-storage you can use the below command.

```
az monitor log-analytics workspace linked-storage delete --type Alerts -g <resource grp> --workspace-name <workspace name>
```

The above command deletes all linked storage accounts with specific data source types for the log analytics workspace.

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[az monitor log-analytics workspace linked-storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/log-analytics/workspace/linked-storage?view=azure-cli-latest)